# Pjax in Symfony

Tags: symfony, pjax

What is the most common way to update a part of a web page with content received from server in Symfony?

Most of my experience with php frameworks is yii2-related, we use pjax for that purpose in Yii2. It's a jQuery plugin, backed with some specific request handling logic on server side, everything is in the framework's core and works fine.

Now I'm looking at Symfony and can't find anything similar.

There are a few bundles that help to integrate pjax into Symfony 
([1](https://github.com/gremo/GremoPjaxBundle) [2](https://github.com/ThreeceeStudios/TcPjaxBundle) [3](https://github.com/Strontium-90/StrontiumPjaxBundle)) but I'm wondering what are the best practices in Symfony for the tasks like these:

- seamlesly apply server side validation to forms, without reloading the page
- update arbitrary parts of a web page with content received from server using ajax

Comment: your question is not related to yii2 so i have removed the `yii2` tag